# Configuring Nuget pack for prerelease on VSTS

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

**Note**
If there is an easier way to create prerelease packages please let me know!

I am using Visual Studio Team Services and have setup a nuget pack and publish step.

I have a build variable called `$(BuildSuffix)` that allows me to tag build-specific variables onto the end of the build number format like so

> $(Build.DefinitionName)_1.0.$(date:yyyy)$(date:MM)$(date:dd)$(rev:.r)$(BuildSuffix)

The idea then is that I can set `$(BuildSuffix)` to `-beta` so that my final build version might be `Build_1.0.20170119.2-beta`.

According to the [nuget documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages), appending `-beta` to a build number will create a prerelease package.  The build in VSTS comes out with -beta appended but the nuget pack stage never seems to contain it.  It always comes out as the exact version number but without the `-beta` tag.

My nuspec files look like this:

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyCompany.Data</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
```

My NuGet package step looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research and bashing my head against a brick wall I figured out how.  You have to:

- Configure a local Build Agent
- Install Nuget CLI
- On Nuget Packager Task set `Path To NuGet.exe` to the NuGet CLI
- Set `NuGet Arguments` on the same screen to `-suffix beta`

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT You cannot mark your own answers as correct until a few days have passed unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 0):

With new NuGet task(version 2) you can specify Additional build properties and there you can pass your custom build number directly instead of using -suffix NuGet argument. Additional build properties are substituting $token$ with supplied value in nuspec and you are free to change whatever you want in there.

I also see it on your screenshot, but I never tried to use it like this with older NuGet tasks as those are deprecated now.

[image: NuGet Packaging Task Group]

Maybe it will be helpful to try import NuGet Packaging Task Group definition I am using on my private projects. Check it out [Here](https://gist.github.com/cloudikka/e3ddf72a7722447267c5679d4efbe176).